# a function that counts the number of odd positive elements in a binary tree

Tags: c++, count, tree, binary

I have homework and I can't understand how to count the odd numbers with recursion in a binary tree

I have tried with for statement, but my teacher said that I need to do with recursion and it will be soo EZ to do, but I can't get it.

```
 // create Tree 


    struct Node
     { 
        int key; 
         Node *left, *right; 
    }; 

    // Function to print all odd nodes 

    void oddNode(Node* root) 
    { 
        if (root != NULL) { 
            oddNode(root->left); 

            // if node is odd then print it 
            if (root->key % 2 != 0) 
                printf("%d ", root->key); 

            oddNode(root->right); 
        } 
    } 
     // Driver Code 

    int main() 

    { 

        /* Let us create following BST 

         5
        / \ 
        3 7 
        / \ / \ 
        2 4 6 8 */
        Node* root = NULL; 
        root = insert(root, 5); 
        root = insert(root, 3); 
        root = insert(root, 2); 
        root = insert(root, 4); 
        root = insert(root, 7); 
        root = insert(root, 6); 
        root = insert(root, 8);

    oddNode(root); 

}
```

The output should be 3, but the actual output is empty

Comment: This seems to be the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okey but the problem is that i don't get error or something like that I just got empty screen that's it .  https://imgur.com/ZHaK3X8

Comment: When I say "debugging" I mean that you need to use a *debugger* to step through the code line by line, stepping into the recursive calls, and see what happens and what values all involved variables have.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes i do and i got  - [Inferior 1 (process 16307) exited normally]

Comment: And was the output of the ***program itself*** wrong or what was expected? By stepping through the program statement by statement you can see *exactly* where it does wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i just can't make the for cycle that will return the odd positive numbers . My output now will return 3,5,7 that is the correct answer but i want too  to return the count of the odd positive elements ? can you help me with cycle please

Comment: So the function `oddNode` should not only print, but also *return*  the count? Then you first of should make it return *something* (just make it return `0` to begin with). Then you need to think about how to add up the result from the recursive calls. Then you need to think about how to add to the sum when the condition is true.

Comment: Recursion is an intuitive way to process trees. (IMHO) Imagine a node which has no children. If key is odd it has to return 1 otherwise 0. A node which has children has to add to this 1 or 0 the number of odd children of `left` (if not `nullptr`) and the number of odd children of `right` (if not `nullptr`) and return this. Recalling my previous sentence, a node with no children is one which just has `left == nullptr` and `right == nullptr`. Hence, the former isn't even a special case of the latter. Does this help?

Comment: @Scheff i do bunch of stuffs but nothing work can you just type the right way , because my teacher said me that will take me 1 min to do , but i can't i trying like 4 hours reserch and nothing please

Comment: Your teacher might assume that you are familiar with making algorithms and writing C++ code all days. (Though, if it was the case - why to attend his course?) ;-)

Comment: 1st: As already suggested you have to change return type of `oddNode()`. If you want to return a value (say `int`), it has to be `int oddNode(Node *root)`. Having this done, you have to add `return` statements (with a return value) at any place where the function may be left.

Comment: A very compact alternative could be: `int oddNode(Node *root) { return root ? oddNode(root->left) + (root->key % 2 != 0) + oddNode(root->right) : 0; }` Thereby, I used the trick that a boolean value can also be used as integral type whereby `false` is 0 and `true` is 1. (In C, it's even the opposite: comparison returns 0 or 1 and this might be interpreted as boolean value as well as C originally had no dedicated boolean values.) It's probably better to modify your function respectively. If you provide my code the teacher might become suspicious... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff void oddNode(Node* root,int *count) 
    { 
    
      int a = root->key;
            // if node is odd then print it 
            if (a % 2 != 0 && a>0) {
          count++;
            oddNode(root->right,&count); 
            oddNode(root->left,&count);   
            }
            
         std::cout<< count;
        
    } and in main function i add int count = 0; and int oddNode(root,&count);  but i dosn't wanne work ?

Comment: RETURN TYPE of function. ;-) Didn't see you that I changed **void** `oddNode()` to **int** `oddNode()`?

Comment: It does: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b994c4c45c15d5b2)

Comment: Get rid of the `count`-thinking. Think recursively! Function returns 0 or 1 for the current node + (PLUS) the number of odd keys of left sub-tree + (PLUS) the number of odd keys of right sub-tree.

Comment: And don't forget that `root` might be a `nullptr`. Your original approach handled this correctly but the one in the "answer" doesn't.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you soo much , but i want to ask you about the code  ? begore oddNode and : 0 mean return 0 ?

Comment: I "de-obfuscated" the previous approach: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5078e8308148c0b) It's still the same algorithm but without the fancy `?:` operator (and printf() added again).

Comment: I assume: your teacher didn't handle `?:` yet? It's the conditional operator: a ? b : c is like if a then b else c. Where if/else are statements the conditional operator forms an expression. The latter is the "functional style" of the former. ;-) (And, btw., it's the only ternary operator of C++ I know - an operator with 3 arguments - hence it needs two operator symbols to separate them: `?` and `:`. They must be used always together.)

Comment: @Scheff The second demo was perfect with word that i can understand . Thank you soo much <3

Comment: You're welcome. Please, don't forget to delete the answer (before it starts to collect down-votes). Or, even better, edit it to show your correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Correct Solution :

```
int oddNode(Node* root) 
{
  int count = 0;
  if (root) {
    count += oddNode(root->left);
    if (root->key % 2 != 0 && root->key>0) {
      printf("%d ", root->key);
      ++count;
    }
    count += oddNode(root->right);
  }
  return count;
} 

// Driver Code 

int main() 
{ 
  /* Let us create following BST 
         5
        / \ 
        3 7 
        / \ / \ 
        2 4 6 8 */
  Node node8 = { 8, nullptr, nullptr };
  Node node6 = { 6, nullptr, nullptr };
  Node node4 = { 4, nullptr, nullptr };
  Node node2 = { 2, nullptr, nullptr };
  Node node7 = { 7, &node6, &node8 };
  Node node3 = { 3, &node2, &node4 };
  Node node5 = { 5, &node3, &node7 };
  Node *root = &node5;
  int count = oddNode(root);
  std::cout
    << "\n"
    << "Number of odd nodes: " << count << '\n'; 
}
```